# Do I lose all my gold when I ascend?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I know that ascending causes me to lose all my hero levels and resets game but do I lose all my gold too?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you lose your gold too.

When you ascend, you get hero souls (1 hero soul for 2000 levels), increasing your damage per second (+10% DPS per hero soul).

Comment: I think it's per 2000 levels.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad

Comment: And each soul gives 10% more dps?

Comment: Yes. And if you buy an ancient, you will lose one heroe soul, and its bonus with it. (and sorry for my bad english (or mistakes). I'm French)

Comment: Your english is at an understandable level. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Just to add: You should spend all your gold for an ascension even on your lower heroes, just to raise the hero souls you gain. 2000 Level are somewhat fast, if you level all of your heroes through.

Answer (score 2):

You will lose all of your gold, except at whichever point you get Ancient Khrysos which gives you enough gold to buy a level one hero depending on the Ancients level from Treebeast (50) to Natalia (100M).

You can also leave an Item drop on the screen after you ascend to get the gold from it at the start of your next world. (drops are little items that differ in appearance on the screen that appear in random locations)